# Como capturar o código de uma tabela gerada via html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, dompdf

Gerei uma tabela com dados pelo HTML e PHP, como faço para gerar uma string dessa tabela com esses dados para que eu possa jogar no meu load_html do DOMPDF?

Comment: Pode parecer meio óbvio, mas tentou no momento da geração criar uma variável e jogar o código dentro? Eu uso dessa forma para gerar uma tabela e enviar por email: $variavel = '<html>.....</html>';

Comment: É porque gerei meus dados através de um while no php. Quero pegar esta tabela já com os dados alimentados

Comment: Dentro do while cria uma variável, clonando a tabela. Vc pode concatenar ela usando $variavel .=

Comment: Poderia postar o código no qual você gera a tabela?

Answer (score 0):

Supor que sua tabela após o `while` tenha sido gerada com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            bla
        </td>
        <td>
            ble
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            bli
        </td>
        <td>
            blo
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Quando o  `while` estiver sendo executado, podemos gerar uma variável com as linhas da tabela da seguinte forma

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     $dados1 = $row["dados1"];
     $dados2 = $row["dados2"];
     $dados3 = $row["dados3"];
     $dados4 = $row["dados4"];
     $strLinhas = "<tr><td>".$dados1."</td><td>".$dados2."</td></tr><tr><td>".$dados3."</td><td>".$dados4."</td></tr>";
}
```

e após o `while` ser executado concatenamos o resultado na variável abaixo

```
$strTabela = "<table>".$strLinhas."</table>";
```